# Google Sheets ImportJSON returns error SyntaxError: Unexpected token: &lt; (line 165)

Tags: json, xml, google-sheets

Here is my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fnkE3s9YLZOJ0pJbX--Tx6OwIJnHlfvpXL4vPlUya6E/edit?usp=drivesdk). I am using a custom (not mine) `ImportJSON function` in Google Sheets to pull in data from [link](https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/export?TYPE=liveScoring&L=64741&APIKEY=&W=1&DETAILS=1&JSON=0?45) and I'm getting an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (line 165)

I don't know how to fix since the file is not mine. I'm using an API to call it.

I looked at line 165 and it looks like every other "player" line. My understanding is that this syntax error can be caused by html or other code that JSON doesn't recognize, but I don't see that happening here.

This is the first thing I've done in JSON and not sure what I did wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: You are pulling data from google sheet to another google sheet using ImportJSON function?

Comment: The linked spreadsheet is my own to show the error. Sorry should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

maybe
=IMPORTXML(URL) ??

this URL show [This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.].

Comment: IMPORTXML displays blank results. Importjson was the workaround I found online

Comment: `=IMPORTXML(URL, query)` .@Bricky, look at these two link(https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/207238327-Use-Google-Sheets-ImportXML-function-to-display-data-in-Geckoboard and https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp ). Hope it helps.